# How to get the Most frequent value from table without using Top, CTE, RowNum and Rank in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have to fetch the most frequent value from the table, I have written the below query and it is giving the expected result.

```
SELECT
    TOP 1 State
FROM
    City
GROUP BY
    State
ORDER BY
    count(State) DESC
```

I know it can be done using CTE, Rank and all, But I am asked to do it without using CTE, Top, Rank, RowNum.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: @Tyron78 you can assume a table with cityname, cityid, state. so multiple cities can belong to the same state (many to one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe `ORDER BY ... OFFSET ... FETCH` is an option:

```
SELECT State
FROM (VALUES
   ('StateA'),
   ('StateA'),
   ('StateA'),
   ('StateB'),
   ('StateB')
) city (State)
GROUP BY State
ORDER BY COUNT(State) DESC OFFSET 0 ROW FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY
```

Result:

```
State
------
StateA
```

Answer (score 0):

Without TOP, ROW_NUMBER etc. the code becomes a little bit uggly, but you can achieve the expected result with subqueries:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  cityname nvarchar(10)
 ,cityid int
 ,statename nvarchar(10)
 ,stateid int
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
(N'City1', 1, N'State1', 1)
,(N'City2', 2, N'State1', 1)
,(N'City3', 3, N'State1', 1)
,(N'City4', 4, N'State2', 2)
,(N'City5', 5, N'State2', 2)

SELECT stateid, statename, cnt
  FROM(SELECT stateid, statename, COUNT(*) cnt
         FROM @t
         GROUP BY stateid, statename
      ) t
  WHERE cnt = (SELECT max(cnt)
                 FROM (SELECT stateid, statename, COUNT(*) cnt
                         FROM @t
                         GROUP BY stateid, statename
                       ) t2
              )
```

Comment: But is this will be slow, you can using 4 select statements

Comment: Yeah, performance won't be so great... but without using the "usual" components like window functions etc. that's the proce for the result... anyways: you could first store the content of the first subquery in a temp. table and use this as source - no idea if this is allowed in your case